# Trying to avoid "attack reported by Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken" message

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I have a new Padrino 0.13.1 project that I am hosting on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker instance. The worker instance has a cron job that calls a POST every 5 minutes in my Padrino app. I have defined the routine as follows:

```
post :myroutine, :with => :myparams, :csrf_protection => false do
  # ... do some stuff
  status 200
end
```

I have also configured `/config/apps.rb` as follows:

```
Padrino.configure_apps do
  set :session_secret, '...'
  set :protection, :except => :path_traversal
  set :protection_from_csrf, true
  set :allow_disabled_csrf, true
end
```

The worker instance does a post to http://localhost:80/myroutine/somevar every 5 minutes. The nginx `access.log` file shows:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2016:04:49:59 +0000] "POST /myroutine/01234 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0" "-"

But in my AWS `production.log` file, I also see this come up every 5 minutes:

> WARN - 21/Mar/2016 04:49:59 attack reported by Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken

Strangely, the routine executes fine, and does what it is supposed to do. I would just like to stop my log file from filling up with the `Rack::Protection` error every 5 minutes.

Is this because of a misconfigured csrf setting somewhere, or a bug?

Comment: In the application configuration, `set :protection_from_csrf, true` line looks contradictory to what you're trying to achieving. Can you check if that's a typo?

Comment: Thanks @Kashyap. The above is what it is in the code.  I have several other POST routines, and I want CSRF protection for those, because they are all called from within my app.  I just have this one routine that gets called from outside my app, so it cannot pass the csrf token like the internal calls do.

Answer (score 1):

it is caused by nginx reverse proxy setting.

which may lost http related information , result session information lost.

https://github.com/znc/znc/issues/946
i just add below line and it works :

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real_IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy   true;
proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
```